# How to spackle a plaster/drywall to firmly hold a magnetic door lock with plastic nails?

Tags: hole, spackling-paste, magnet

The problem is that the wall half of the magnet has come off the wall, leaving a hole in the wall. I tried to plug the hole in the wall with DryDex Sparkling & Nail Hole Filler, but it was not solid enough to hold the magnet's nails after drying overnight. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

Usually something like this:

- Enlarge the hole to something like 4 x 6 inches.
- Cut a scrap of drywall about 5.5 x 8.
- Drill a couple of holes in the center of the patch.
- Tie a loop of cord through the pair of holes.  Leave enough slack to get a good grip.
- Maneuver the patch through the hole, rotate it to cover the hole, then secure with dry wall screws
- Cut a second piece of drywall to fit the hole.  Screw it to the back patch.
- Drywall mud and tape the seam.
- Drill holes for drywall anchors, or use the plastic screw-in anchors.
- Use appropriate screws to mount through the magnet plate into the anchors. ...

Comment: Instead of the larger piece of drywall, one could use a piece of 1x3 or other wood to support the patch. The added advantage is that the wood could be placed exactly where the latch should mount, thus providing some extra grip for the screws/nails for the latch.

Answer (score 0):

If it tore out before it will tear out again.  Your best bet is to make up a nice wooden board, varnish and stain it, that is large enough to cover over both studs, and then bolt or screw it into the studs on top of the drywall, covering the hole.  Then the maglock mounts to the board.